# There was an error deserializing the object of type Boolean, The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Boolean'?

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf

I have a WCF service which has a data member

```
    [DataMember(Name = "callToPhone")]
    public bool IsCallToPhone { get; set; }
```

inside one of the DataContracts. When I call this service and pass "" for the variable IsCallToPhone, I get a deserialization error. I understand that the an empty value cannot be passed to a Bool, but is there any way we could make it accept the value and assign a default false for such case.

This is my error

```
    {
"message": "There was an error deserializing the object of type SciGame.CMP.API.Contracts.Player.CreatePlayerRequest. The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Boolean'."
```

}

What I tried - I tried by making the variable as a nullable type.

```
     public bool? IsCallToPhone { get; set; }
```

also tried to implement the getter and setter property

```
            public bool IsCallToPhone
    {
        get { return IsCallToPhone; }
        set
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(value) == "")
            {
                value = false;
            }
            IsCallToPhone = value;
        }
    }
```

Either of these is not working, is there anything wrong that I am doing

Comment: Your code in the current property is not being executed at all coz it is failing even before that when empty string in being assigned to the property. You need to have `IsCallToPhone` property as string. You can have another property of boolean Type where you can have logic to return true or false based on the string property.

Comment: `""` is not a valid `bool` value according to the JSON standard https://json.org/.  A Boolean value should look like `true` or `false`.  If you make the property nullable then `null` would also be allowed.  But there's no defined mapping between an empty string and a `bool`.

Comment: Well if you are using [tag:wcf] with [tag:json] in the .Net full framework, then the serializer used is `DataContractJsonSerializer`.  The only way to do what you want there is to use a surrogate `string` property and parse the incoming string yourself.  What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, full traceback and inner exception(s) if any?  That should indicate the serializer being used.

Comment: Okay, so i achieved this using a string variable which takes the value and then assigns it to the bool variable. Thanks :)